# XAMPP - PHP script will not display in HTML file

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am running XAMPP and Apache. I have two files:

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>php script</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
echo "hello world";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**post.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>html page</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>

var xhr;
xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost/demoApp/index.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want **post.html** to call **index.php** so that **post.html** displays "hello world" on the html page. When I open **index.php**, I see "hello world."

I also know that **post.html** is calling **index.php** because I have other script that when copied into **index.php** will successfully send me an email if I open **post.html**.

If **post.html** is indeed calling **index.php**, why is my echo not displaying on **post.html**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

post.html is making a request, but you're not actually doing anything with that request. When using ajax, javascript is making the call and you need to tell it explicitly what you would like to do with the response.

To simply alert the remote content, listen on the [`onreadystatechange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState), and when it's 4 (Complete), show an alert:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr.readyState==4) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
```

If you wish to append the data anywhere (Without using jQuery), I recommending assigning a div with an ID, and appending or assigning the data:

index.php:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
echo "hello world";
?>
```

post.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>html page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="remote_content"></div>
<script>

var xhr;
xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost/demoApp/index.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr.readyState !== 4)
        return;

    document.getElementById('remote_content').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
}
xhr.send();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. In all my research it was my understanding that by POSTing to the server containing the PHP script, the PHP script would be executed on my HTML page.

Comment: It's true when accessing the script directly, not in an AJAX context where you need to tell the script what to do with the output of the page you're posting to.